# uinput virtual device and /dev/input/mice

Tags: linux, input, kernel, uinput

I have created a virtual mouse by writing data in /dev/uinput.

However it seems that the data are not the same in /dev/input/eventX (where my mouse is) and /dev/input/mice.

I don't use another mouse.

How is this thing possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/dev/input/mice` provides data in the [PS/2 mouse protocol](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-13.html).

`/dev/input/event*` use the Linux input event interface (`struct input_event` structures as described in `/usr/include/linux/input.h`).